# Multiple Integration of a line and an ellipse.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $A$ be the area of the region in the first quadrant bounded by the line $y=\dfrac{1}{2}x$, the x-axis, and the ellipse $\dfrac{1}{9}x^2+y^2=1$. Find the positive number $m$ such that A is equal to the area of the region in the first quadrant bounded by the line $y=mx$, the y-axis, and the ellipse mentioned.

I know it would help for me to tell you what I've done so far, but conics are always a problem for me.

Comment: I'm possibly tired, but this doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: @MarkFantini An edit was made to the boundaries of the second statement. should make more sense now